# Arduino 16 Megahertz, how fast is my program running?

Tags: arduino, cpu

So, in theory how many times per second will the loop function be executed?

Can this be calculated based on the Megahertz? Arduino runs at 16 Megahertz

Comment: It runs at 16 Megahertz, not Hertz. And no, it can't really be calculated, it depends on what functions you call and how long it takes the functions to do whatever they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gerald said, you cannot simply take the clock frequency and calculate the loop method's iterations per second, some functions take long, some dont, what about delay(1000) and conditionals?

If your program needs to know how many times the loop is happening per second you can use the `millis` and `micros` methods. For example you can count the amount of times the loop has looped and save every second by monitoring `millis` or `micros`.